# Why are we current observing 504 gateway timeout errors when using the excel graph api?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Request URL:https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/4c9d60af-5c54-4628-b483-905fd23ed9db/drive/root:/folder/workbook.xlsx:/workbook/worksheets%28%27worksheet1%27%29/tables%28%27table1%27%29/columns%28%27type%27%29/filter/apply

Request Method:POST
Status Code:504 Gateway Timeout

{
  "error": {
    "code": "UnknownError",
    "message": "",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "71f705fb-3414-46a3-99bf-69b21d494fe0",
      "date": "2017-06-26T11:18:37"
    }
  }
}