# Excel Graph API: periodic 504 Gateway Timeout errors

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Usually my code works great, but about 15% of tries, I receive the following error:

```
System.Net.WebException: 
  The remote server returned an error: (504) Gateway Timeout. 
  at System.Net.WebClient.UploadDataInternal(…
```

My c# code does the following:

- Gets graph API Excel access token and session (this is always
  successful)
- Sets values in 2-8 ranges (depending on what
  data/calculations are needed)
- Gets calculated values from several
  ranges
- Gets several updated graphs

The process takes a total of 4-12 seconds to get all needed results back.
But sometimes one of the "set values" operations returns the 504 Gateway Timeout error.

Here is the code I use to set values (update ranges).  It loops through this several times to update multiple ranges.

```cs
string rangeValues = "{\"values\" :[" + rowValues + "]}";
using(WebClient wc = new WebClient())
{
    wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/json";
    wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Authorization] = "Bearer " + Access_Token;
    wc.Headers["workbook-session-id"] = WorkBook_SessionId;
    URI = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root:/EwaReportWorkbooks/" +
        ToolPathAndName +
        ":/workbook/worksheets('" + sheetName +
        "')/range(address='" + rangeName + "')";
    Data = rangeValues;
    wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/json";
    wc.UploadString(URI, "PATCH", Data);
}
```

I see that a couple other people have similar issues:

- [Gateway Timeout on Group Drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45381774/gateway-timeout-on-group-drive)
- [Why are we current observing 504 gateway timeout errors when using the excel graph api?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44758658/why-are-we-current-observing-504-gateway-timeout-errors-when-using-the-excel-gra)

One response indicates this may be a known issue.  But the solutions don't seem applicable in my case (no UI for user to wait for).

I understand that extending my `WebClient` timeout will not help (it is a remote server issue).

Does this issue occur because I am setting, then getting, ranges too fast (one after another)?  If so, how much should my code pause between them?  Or is there some way to sense when the API is ready for more operations?

Or is there another solution?

Comment: I've been struggling with 504 when I was fetching the large amount ~ 2k rows of data from an excel sheet. Firstly, I distributed the data in different sheets and then I used batch which enables the user to merge multiple get and post requests and club multiple responses in one. It's faster.
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/json_batching